# How do I pass all the environment variables from my shell to the bash script it calls?

Tags: django, python-3.x, bash, environment-variables, migration

I'm running Python 3.7, Django 2, on Mac OS X.  When I run the following commands from the command line, they work seamlessly ...

```
localhost:web davea$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) localhost:web davea$ python manage.py migrate maps
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: maps
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

However, when I create a bash script containing the commands

```
!#/bin/bash
source ./venv/bin/activate
python manage.py migrate maps
```

The script dies

```
localhost:web davea$ sh test.sh 
test.sh: line 1: !#/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I have figured out with the help of my friends in comments, that the problem is due to some env vars not being accessible from my bash script.  Rather than cherry-pick specific vars, I would like to know how to pass my entire set of environment vars to the script before it runs.

Comment: Typo: `!#/bin/bash` -> `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I don't use OS X, but I think `source` is bash-specific and not valid in `sh`. Have you tried to run the script using `./test.sh`?

Comment: @Flux, Gave that a go, but got the same error. (Also corrected typo pointed out in other comment)

Comment: What's the output of `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your shell, and in your script?

Comment: In the normal shell, it's /usr/local/mysql/lib, but in the script it's empty.

Comment: So try adding `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/mysql/lib'` to your script.

Comment: So that worked.  Is there any way I can configure the script to environment variables of the shell that's calling it?  I would like to prevent having to hard-code the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: You could run your script using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ./test.sh`.

Comment: It will help if you will share the content of './venv/bin/activat'. By definition, all ENV are passed down, but it's possible to "break" this logic. More specifically, look at "aliases" and "functions" which are not inherited. Possible that 'python' is aliases to something else in the 'activate' script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your start line as below

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
source ./venv/bin/activate
python manage.py migrate maps
```

The `-l` flag will make sure that your bash profile is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sh` to run shell scripts (unless that's *really* the shell you want, which is rare). `sh` is *not* the same shell as `bash`. Either invoke it with `bash` instead, or fix your `!#/bin/bash` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to `#!/bin/bash` and simply invoke the script directly; this is generally easier to manage (and fewer characters to type...).

I suspect simply using the correct shell will be enough to solve your problem, but if not you need to figure out where `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is being set (presumably either your `~/.bashrc` or `venv/bin/activate`) and ensure the variable is being `export`-ed. Bash variables are not environment variables by default, you need to `export` them in order to tell bash to include them in the env variables for any subprocesses that are invoked.

Comment: So I understand your answer, you're saying if I just run it as "./test.sh" (without the "sh"), I should inherit the env vars?  Taht is not what's happening when I run just "./test.sh" all by itself.  Ditto for running "bash ./test.sh"

Comment: If you run `sh ./test.sh` your script is parsed and run by `sh`, which is presumably not intended. If you run `bash ./test.sh` or `./test.sh` (with a fixed shebang) *bash* will run your script instead. Once you're running the correct shell it will be easier to diagnose any further issues. Like I said, check whether these variables *actually* are in your environment - if they're not being picked up by subprocesses that usually means they aren't in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would try script this:

```
!#/bin/bash
./venv/bin/python manage.py migrate maps
```

Explanation:

from "Creation of virtual environments"
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

> You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation
>   just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path,
>   so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter
>   and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full
>   path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should
>   be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual
>   environment’s Python automatically.